# Declaration variable with type in variable of type 'Type'

Tags: c#, .net

I have variable in my class with type of 'Type':

```
class A
{
    public static Type MyType;
}
```

And I declared this variable with anywhere construction. Example:

```
A.MyType = b.GetType();
```

First problem: I need declare new variable with type stored in MyType.

```
<MyType> myValue = new <MyType>;
```

Second problem: I need a function that indicates whether reducible to each other variables of the 'Type'.

Comment: maybe [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.80).aspx) can help you..

Comment: *I need declare new variable with type stored in MyType.*: You mean you want to create an instance of that type?

Comment: What do you want to implement ? I dont understand the sense in this code. Perhaps there is a more simple way?

Comment: Type myValue = typeof(int);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> First problem: I need declare new variable with type stored in MyType.

You can't do this, basically.

Variable types need to be known at *compile-time*. You can't declare a variable using a type which is only known at execution time. You can get *some* of the way there using generics:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private T value;
}
```

You can even add a constraint to require that `T` has a parameterless constructor which you can then call:

```
public class Foo<T> : new()
{
    private T value = new T();
}
```

... and you could create a `Foo<T>` when you only know the type of `T` at execution time using reflection:

```
Type genericDefinition = typeof(Foo<>);
Type constructed = genericDefinition.MakeGenericType(A.MyType);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

... but it will get messy pretty quickly. You haven't told us anything about what you're actually trying to achieve, so it's hard to suggest an alternative - but if you can possibly redesign to avoid this, I would.

> Second problem: I need a function that indicates whether reducible to each other variables of the 'Type'

It's possible that you're looking for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), but it's not clear...